# How to and what components manually should be troubleshooted in Kubernetes using shell script

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I am trying write a `bash` script to troubleshoot a `kubernetes cluster`

I have a `kubernetes cluster` with one `master node` and few `minions`.

I am trying to write a script to troubleshoot the cluster which finally outputs **a detailed report with errors(if existed) and successes**

**Q.) What I really need to know is, what steps should I follow and what components should I be testing/checking during the troubleshoot. I need a list of procedures, steps (maybe in bullet form) on how to troubleshoot a `Kubernetes Cluster` `manually`**

PS: I don't want to use `kubernetes` in-built testing mechanism, I need it to be manually tested/troubleshooted.

Any one here can give me a good descriptive mechanism/steps?

Comment: Please describe the depth of errors! Errors in Kubernetes can be myraid and just by calling it *errors* makes it difficult to understand!

Comment: Troubleshooting a kubernetes cluster. What should be the steps, if you were to troubleshoot an entire cluster, where do you start from and so on?

Comment: kubernetes has many movable components networking, storage,...etc. you need to specify what you want to troubleshoot!

Comment: Every component. Where should I start? Imagine this is like a in-built troubleshoot we do in our laptops. We never know what is really going inside, but it always gives an error or a success saying WiFi troubleshoot is completed, here are the results. Likewise I need to troubleshoot a whole cluster, need to have an understanding of what really should I be testing where I should start from-to components/areas

Answer (score 0):

You need to check below services on master to confirm that kubernetes is functioning fine

1. docker should be running
2. kubelet should be running ( if you run control-plane components in containers )
3. etcd
4. kubernetes scheduler
5. kubernetes controller manager
6. kubernetes components health ( `kubectl get cs` )
7. all services in kube-system should be running ( `kubectl get pods -n kube-system` )

Comment: Finally someone with an answer. Thank you sir. Do you have anything more to add to this?

Comment: It would be better if you could specify each point more for a clear clarification?